# How do I make my bot mention rather than print <@[userid]>?

Tags: discord.py

I'm trying to make a python discord bot that takes in a mention as an input, which is working, but when it comes to the output, the title doesn't mention the user, but the description in the embed does (screenshot attached). How do I make it mention rather than printing <@[userid]>? Thanks in advance.
[image][image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not mention role/user/channel in embed's title and embed's field name

Use the description or field's value, that's where mentions work